# Does sifr 3 works in all desktop's A-Grade browsers?

Tags: javascript, xhtml, sifr, flash, sifr3

Does sifr 3 works in all A-Grade browser if css, javascript is enabled and flash player is installed.

[A-Grade browser http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/448/6837085829.png](http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/448/6837085829.png)

and which Flash player version is needed to see sifr 3 text in all browsers.

Comment: Please consider supporting Mobile Safari.

Comment: Iphone do not support flash so sifr3 will not work on iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes. See below links for verification.

From their documentation:

1. [Supported Browsers](http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr3/Supported+browsers)
2. [How to Use](http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr3/How+to+use) (States to use Flash 8 in the build settings, which means 8 is the min version. [Flash penetration stats here](http://www.adobe.com/products/player_census/flashplayer/version_penetration.html))

Comment: Is it confirm that Iphone do not support Flash so sifr3 text will not shown in iphone safari?

Comment: That is correct. Apple has not allowed Flash to run on the iPhone, and sifr would not be shown on the iPhone.

Comment: You might want to look into Cufon which will work on the iPhone, to my knowledge: http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/